# $_POST not working. "Notice: Undefined index: username..."

Tags: php, http-post, undefined-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

So, I am currently learning PHP and was reading on a book about the md5 function for passwords, so I decided to give it a try and see how it goes. I also decided to use the POST method rather than the GET, since I saw people saying that it is safer and doesn't let the variables appearing on the URL.

For my testing project I made a very simple form, which follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="dologin" method="POST">
            <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I enter the values on BOTH fields and click "Login" I get the following output on the other PHP file.

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\md5\home\dologin\index.php on line 11
Username non existent
```

Here follows the code for the "/dologin/index.php" file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
            $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if(isset($row)){
                $password = (mysql_result($result,$row - 1));
                $enteredpassword = md5("w@#$@#".$_GET['password']."^#3f%#^");
                if($password == $enteredpassword){
                    if(!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])){
                        session_start();
                    }
                    $_SERVER['LOGIN_STATUS'] = true;
                } else {
                    die("Access denied");
                }    
            } else {
                die("Username non existent");
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help at all on my issue is very much appreciated, thank you for reading.

Comment: Seems more likely you would get an undefined index notice on `$_GET['password']` since this form was sent as a POST.

Comment: Before you continue with this project, [start reading about SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and the use of prepared statements. The old `mysql_*()` functions will be deprecated in the next major PHP release, and you are advised to switch to a newer API like PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: pssstt: At the top of the your logic (index.php) file, throw this in there: var_dump($_POST); That will allow you to see what you're passing from page to page.

Comment: do a var_dump on `$_POST` (`var_dump($_POST)`). Post the result please xD

Comment: Also, I hope the `$_GET['password']` is just a typo. You really shouldn't be passing passwords through URL queries.

Comment: $_GET was a typo indeed.

Comment: Maybe if you set your action to dologin/index.php -- Windows can be annoying like that sometime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*undefined index* means that somewhere in the $_POST array, there isn't an index (key) for the key **username**.

You should be setting your posted values into variables for a more clean solution, and it's a good habit to get into.

If I was having a similar error, I'd do something like this:

```
$username = $_POST['username']; // you should really do some more logic to see if it's set first
echo $username;
```

If username didn't turn up, that'd mean I was screwing up somewhere. You can also,

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

To see what you're posting. var_dump is really useful as far as debugging. Check it out: [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump)

Comment: I get "NULL" on var_dump, I knew that there was nothing being passed between pages. The problem is that I can't figure out why is that, since that's the way I've always being doing and has worked so far.

Answer (score 3):

You should check if the `POST['username']` is defined. Use this above:

```
$username = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}

"SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'"
```

Answer (score 3):

first of all,

be sure that there is a post

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) { 
    // check if the username has been set
}
```

second, and most importantly, sanitize the data, meaning that

```
$query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'";
```

is deadly dangerous, instead use

```
$query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'";
```

and please research the subject [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection)